# Cast a mocked object throws ClassCastException

Tags: junit, junit4, easymock, powermock

I have a object which I mock using powermock while unit testing.

```
ClassA mockedClassA = PowerMock.createMock(ClassA.class);
```

Later in mycode I'm using that object with a cast. Life follows.

```
String hello = ((ClassB)classA).someMethod();
```

Junit test throws following exception at thie place.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy15 incompatible with ClassB
```

It looks like casting the mocked object is not possible. So how can I go through this?

I tried following thigs.

Easymock.expect((ClassB)mockedClassA.somemethod())...;

doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code expects classA to be a ClassB object, but it is not (unless ClassA extends ClassB, but then you wouldn't need the cast). Have you tried

```
ClassA mockedClassA = PowerMock.createMock(ClassB.class)
```